# Identify user Authentication provider - FBA vs Domain

Tags: 2013, authentication, forms-authentication

I have a SharePoint website configured to use both Windows (AD) Authentication and SQL Authentication with Forms based authentication..

I want to query all Form Based Authentication users.. Is there a property or anything that I can identify if the current user is FBA User or Windows (AD) user..

I know I can use UserName and see if Domain\Username is the pattern than the user is AD User.. Is there any other method? What if I want to Query all FBA Users and apply some operation!

I am planning is to make a separate List (maybe External Users) and once registered place all the FBA Users in that.. But do I have any other choice?

**EDIT**
One more thing I can think of is using [membership.GetUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40w5063z.aspx) to identify if the he is the external user!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fba menmbers are stored in FBA Database so you can query using the following:

Membership.GetAllUsers method which will return all FBA users.

Comment: Is there any SharePoint specific code I can use ? Differentiating them from Windows Users?

Comment: Your query seems not clear to me. If you simply want to populate all FBA users to one place so you can get the users from FBA Db. On what input values you want to differentiate. Could you mention that in brief.

Comment: I was just confirming this is the only way and there is nothing in SharePoint from which I can identify if the user if form based or windows! Your answer is correct, I am looking into other answers (if there are any)